# Bash environment variable that is equivalent to -x?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bunch of scripts that I am debugging, all nested and quite nasty.

Just wondering if I'm able to set some environment variable that is equivalent of the -x option to bash.  This will save me amazing amounts of time.

I have searched for the answer, but seems it doesn't exist - hoping you smart folks might be able to offer advice, or perhaps an alternative solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you seem like you're in dire straits, I'll suggest some horrible options (and one option that sounds horrible, but isn't so bad).

First choice: use a different tool. `strace(1)` and `ltrace(1)` can both give an amazing array of information -- though neither one understand anything about the shell variables, they *will* show you how the scripts interact with the rest of the system and some of the internal states of the program. It might be good enough. (If you're new to `strace(1)`, try `strace -f -o /tmp/foo ./program` -- it'll follow `fork(2)`, `vfork(2)`, and `clone(2)` calls, so child processes are followed and dumped too. Output goes to `/tmp/foo`.)

Second choice: replace all the `#!/bin/bash` with `#!/bin/bash -x` in all your scripts:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e 's/^#!\/bin\/bash$/#!\/bin\/bash -x/'
```

Perhaps there's a better mechanism for replacing the shebang line on all your scripts, but this feels alright. It'll miss all the uses of `system(3)`, `popen(3)`, etc., in C programs called via your scripts, but that might be just fine. If any scripts rely on arguments to `/bin/bash`, you may need to work harder to add `-x` properly.

Very last choice: start a `sash(1)` shell as root. Copy `/bin/bash` to `/bin/real.bash`. Write a quick-and-dirty C program that will add `-x` to the command line arguments to `/bin/real.bash`, and *place it into `/bin/bash`*. This will get *everything*: every `system(3)`, every `popen(3)`, every init script, all cron jobs, all user logins, everything.

You could modify that very last choice a little bit; the Linux kernel provides per-process private namespaces that can be used to make a new `/bin/bash` visible to just *children* of a given process. It's a little more complicated...

1. Make a copy of `bash`: `cp /bin/bash /bin/real.bash`
2. Write your C wrapper to add `-x` to the command line arguments and call `/bin/real.bash`. (Lets call it `/bin/wrapper.bash`.)
3. Make the `/` mount `shared`: `mount --make-shared /`
4. Create a new filesystem namespace: `unshare --mount bash`
5. Within the *new* `bash`, make `/` a slave: `mount --make-slave /`
6. Within the *new* `bash`, bind-mount your replacement `bash`: `mount -B /bin/wrapper.bash /bin/bash`
7. Within the *new* `bash`, start your shell scripts. They will all be redirected to your wrapper. Processes not descended from the *new* `bash` will continue to use the "real" `/bin/bash`, which remained unmodified.

When the last (grand)*child process dies, so does the private namespace and the funny bind mount.

The upshot of all this funny business is that all your shell scripts remain unchanged and you get to use the debugging tool you thought would be most useful. If you squint your eyes just right, it isn't very intrusive.

I performed many of these steps on my workstation (except I used `--make-rshared` and `--make-rslave` instead, and tested with `/bin/dir` and `/bin/ls` instead of `/bin/bash`), and checked the inode numbers with `ls -li /bin/dir /bin/ls` from shells within the new namespace and outside the new namespace, and processes outside the namespace continued to see the inode numbers remain unchanged but processes within the namespace saw `dir` and `ls` share inode numbers.

For full details of the namespaces, private mounts, and bind mounts, I recommend reading the [`Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt`](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt) file from the kernel source tree, the `clone(2)` manual page, the `unshare(1)` manual page, and the `mount(8)` manual page.

Bind mounts go away on system reboots, so you can't screw anything up too badly. :)

Comment: Thanks; I've had "really learn about private namespaces and shared subtrees" on my to-do list for ages and this seemed like the perfect application.

Comment: It's probably sufficient to say `mv /bin/bash /bin/bash.real ; printf '#!/bin/bash.real\n/bin/bash.real -x "$@"\n' > /bin/bash ; chmod a+x /bin/bash` and not bother with C.

Comment: @Sorpigal that only works with fairly recent Linux kernels -- older kernels don't work properly with a shebang pointing at a script that has a shebang.

Comment: Thank you sir!  I wrote myself a little C replacement :-)   I had already been down the strace road to little avail.

Comment: The `execve(2)` manpage on my system still claims that the interpreter specified on an interpreter script cannot itself be a script -- I had no idea that more recent kernels relaxed that restriction, in which case, @Sorpigal's little script is definitely easier than the equivalent C wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not controlled by an environment variable, but you can do `set -x` where you need to, and `set +x` to turn it back off.